# Cross Join Performance issue

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query which is performing very slow .

```
SELECT  A.city_id
            , FIRST_Hotel_By_City.hotel_name        
    FROM    hotel AS A  
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT  TOP 1 I.*
                FROM    hotel AS I
                WHERE   A.city_id = I.city_id
                ORDER   BY I.created_date ASC , hotel_name ASC
            ) FIRST_Hotel_By_City
    GROUP BY A.city_id
            , FIRST_Hotel_By_City.hotel_name
            , FIRST_Hotel_By_City.created_date
    ORDER BY A.city_id
```

I have the below non clustered index on City_id

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_cityid
  ON hotel(city_id )
  include (created_date, hotel_name)
```

Can somebody please help if we can optimize it further. Below are the stats and execution plan for the query.

[Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nTc3.png) ,
[ExecutionPlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X40VP.png)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your query and the output you are getting, I think you don't need a `CROSS APPLY`,  you can simplify change your query like following for better performance.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT city_id,hotel_name  FROM
    (
        SELECT A.city_id,
        (
         SELECT TOP 1 hotel_name FROM hotel I  WHERE   A.city_id = I.city_id
         ORDER BY  I.created_date ASC , hotel_name ASC
        ) AS hotel_name
        FROM hotel  A
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

For each `city_id` you are trying to return the `hotel_name` of the hotel ordered first by `created_date ASC, hotel_name ASC`.

You can use (**<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/OUVU71633)</kbd>**)

```
SELECT city_id,
       MIN(created_date) AS created_date,
       SUBSTRING(MIN(STR(DATEDIFF(DAY,'0001-01-01',created_date)) + hotel_name), 11, 8000)
FROM   hotel
GROUP  BY city_id
```

which gives a simple execution plan with a single index scan.

[image]